# Как называется кнопка для работы с dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Как называется кнопка для работы с dataGridView
т.е. на кнопку нажал добавить ячейку или удалить

Comment: Кнопка - код... Ну а вообще, укажите меткой что у вас за платформа `WinForms` или `WPF`. В WPF достаточно привязать правильно коллекцию и пойдет все по как по маслу...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  Да , WinForms

Answer (score 0):

Маленькая стрелка в правом верхнем углу. Как называется? Tasks, вероятно, называется.

[image: кнопка]